# Idrac 6 internet settings enabled to connect to internet via ssh

Tags: dell, connection, internet, drac

I just installed the idrac 6 enterprise into dell r410.
I insert the cable on it.
But there is no connection.
Green light on  !!
Normally when i restart the server and when I use the normal connection like em1, I have to use command code for connecting to internet.
I'm using the code ifup em1.
But i don't know the command code for idrac 6.
My server cannot connect to internet automatically like computers.

I just installed the idrac 6 enterprise and i restart the server using the command `ctrl+e` to setup internet setting.
I just turned on idrac 6 in there.
Do i need any extra setting or installation?
I tried to log in from dell to the idrac6 system.
But its says wrong password or username.
I'm using the username and password  which i set up under `ctrl+e` idrac settings.
If there is any command code like `ifup em1` for idrac 6  please let me know.
Or do i need any other settings for idrac 6 enterprise?
I check that from dell support panel I tried to follow the instructions but i didn't understand them.

And i need to setup and use dell idrac 6 flash card I just insert it into card thats all.
I don't know how i will setup flash card as well.

Thanks for help

Comment: Proper. [punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation). is. your. friend. Please re-write for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to configure the iDRAC for network access (outwith the defaults specified in the Dell Documentation), you will need to access the iDRAC at boot-time by pressing `ctrl+E` keys to interrupt the BIOS POST procedure, which will give you the option to directly access and configure the iDRAC.

Once you have accessed the iDRAC and configured the network settings to your needs, you will be able to access it via its IP (or hostname, if you have registered it in DNS), with the default username and password combo (also specified by the documentation) which should be:

username = `root`

password = `calvin`

You can find more complete information by following the relevant links on [this Dell Documentation page](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/3204.dell-remote-access-controller-drac-idrac/)

Comment: i press the f12 key  but its says no file for boot

Comment: Apologies, although it's possible to access it via f12, the Dell Documentation linked above instructs that you use `CTRL+E`; I have updated my answer accordingly. Please refer to the documentation's 'Basic Installation of the iDRAC6' section for the rest of your configuration queries.